# Using condition to select the sorting property in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am using `sortedBy()` to perform sorting on the collection of objects.

Since the order may change depending on the user choice, I've ended up with the following code

```
val sortedList = if (sortingOrder == WordSortingOrder.BY_ALPHA) {
                    list.sortedBy { it.word.value }
                } else {
                    list.sortedBy { it.createdAt }
                }
```

Then I perform further actions on the sorted collection.
I realize that `sortedBy()` method expects a property to be returned.
I wonder if there is a way to embed the sorting condition in one chain of collection methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your properties are of different types you won't be able to select one of them based on some condition as a result for `sortedBy`, as their common supertype would be inferred as `Any` and it is not a subtype of `Comparable<R>` as `sortedBy` expects.

Instead you can utilize `sortedWith` method, which takes a `Comparator`, and provide a comparator depending on the condition:

```
list.sortedWith(
    if (sortingOrder == WordSortingOrder.BY_ALPHA)
        compareBy { it.word.value }
    else
        compareBy { it.createdAt }
)
```

Comparators for different properties are created here with the [`kotlin.comparisons.compareBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.comparisons/compare-by.html) function.

You can then extract the logic which selects comparator based on sorting order to a function:

```
list.sortedWith(comparatorFor(sortingOrder))

fun comparatorFor(sortingOrder: WordSortingOrder): Comparator<MyType> = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sortedBy` expects **any** function of type `(T) -> R` as its parameter. A property is a corner case of that.

Which means you can do this:

```
val sortedList = list
    .sortedBy { if (sortingOrder == WordSortingOrder.BY_ALPHA) it.word.value else it.createdAt}
```

Or, if you need something more OOP-ish:

```
enum class WordSortingOrder(val transform: (MyObject) -> Int) {
    BY_ALPHA({it.word.value}), 
    BY_ALPHA_REVERSED({-1 * it.word.value}),
    DEFAULT({it.createdAt})
}

val sortedList = list.sortedBy { sortingOrder.transform(it)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the lambda argument passed to `sortedBy` conditional:

```
list.sortedBy(if (sortingOrder == WordSortingOrder.BY_ALPHA) {
    { it: MyType -> it.word.value }
} else {
    { it: MyType -> it.createdAt }
})
```

You may find using `when` instead of `if` more readable in this scenario:

```
list.sortedBy(when (sortingOrder) {
    WordSortingOrder.BY_ALPHA -> { it: MyType -> it.word.value }
    else -> { it: MyType -> it.createdAt }
})
```

If your selectors have different return types then you can simply wrap your existing code within `list.let { list -> ... }` or use `run`:

```
list.run {
    if (sortingOrder == WordSortingOrder.BY_ALPHA) {
        sortedBy { it.word.value }
    } else {
        sortedBy { it.createdAt }
    }
}
```

You can then continue chainging calls after the `let`/`run`.

Comment: For me the latter code shows an compiler error:
`inferred type Any is not a subtype of Comparable<Any>`
I guess this happens because 
`it.word.value` and `it.createdAt` have different return types

Comment: Since the properties have different types casting the return values inside to `Comparable<Any>` is required in order to avoid compiler errors. With the casting it doesn't look that nice anymore so probably having the code as in the question is a better solution. Also it allows to easily switch between ascending and descending orders.

Comment: Good point @Zzokk. I did not consider that before. I've added another example which uses `run`. You can basically wrap any group of operations in a `let` or `run` block and continue chaining after it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
list.sortedBy { item ->
    when(sortingOrder) {
        WordSortingOrder.BY_ALPHA -> item.word.value
        else                      -> item.createdAt
    }
}
```